# Tensorflow error - tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError - on running command rasa init --no-prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, rasa

When I run rasa init --no-prompt I am getting the above error. I am not able to debug the cause for this error, Above are the commands I have used to install Rasa.

**pip3 install rasa**

**pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow rasa**

**pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-addons rasa**

**pip install --upgrade pip**

**pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-addons rasa --use-feature=2020-resolver**

Above are my details of the versions used

**Rasa version:
1.10.10**

**Python version:
3.6.9**

**Operating system
Ubuntu 18.04.4 64 bit**

**tensorflow 2.3.0**

**tensorflow-addons<0.8.0,>=0.7.1**

I am getting the above error, my virtual env is activated.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/aman/meraklis-pocs/RASA_POC/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_addons/custom_ops/activations/_activation_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow14kernel_factory17OpKernelRegistrar12InitInternalEPKNS_9KernelDefEN4absl11string_viewESt10unique_ptrINS0_15OpKernelFactoryESt14default_deleteIS8_EE
```

Comment: Could you add the error with the full traceback? That makes it easier to debug. Also, feel free to use the markdown syntax on project settings as well. Makes it easier to read.

Comment: @cantdutchthis Okay the post was becoming too big so I didn't, Anyways its solved. I just uninstalled venv and upgraded pip and also installed dev build essential g++ and reinstalled everything again including RASA and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, rasa is compatible just with TensorFlow version 2.1.1 and python 3.6 or python 3.7

Try to uninstall any other version of tensorflow and install 2.1.1 of TensorFlow.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.1.1
```

This should work, incase any issue let me know.

P.S - Give it try in new virtual environment as well.

Comment: Yes thanks. I already have fixed it, Using tensorflow=2.1.1 version currently and its working fine.