# Virtual Environment Settings for Rasa

Tags: python, tensorflow, compatibility, rasa

I have been building a Chatbot following Rasa for a while. I create a venvs for it, called Chatbot. T have tried many versions of different packs or frameworks, such as Python(3.8, 3.7, ...), Tensorflow (1.13, 1.15, 2.1, 2.2), conda (4.5.12, 4.8, ...) and pip (20.1.1, 20.2). However, I couldn't train and run my Rasa chatbot because of continuous errors like incompatibility between those installation, despite my finding and searching on lots of reference for those failure.

---

Now I feel quite exhausted and depressed. So how could I figure out the best solution for this problem (which version of those lib could work well together), anyone who succeeded in developing Rasa chatbot could help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I use conda and it works well with rasa (conda-4.8.4, python-3.7.7, pip-20.2.2, rasa-1.10.10). Note: Rasa requires Python 3.6 or 3.7

```
conda create --name rasa_test python=3.7
conda activate rasa_test
conda install -c anaconda pip
conda update --all
pip install rasa
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I still came up against with another error. To be detailed, when I run pip3 install rasa, the process stops when coming to ujson package, and "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required" as well. I have tried many ways shown in StackOverFlow, Github or Rasa Community. I installed MS tools, VS Studio 2019, install ujson directly but the error still appears. Any idea about that? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

**I can understand your pain!**

You just need to take care of 2 things: Tensorflow version and Python version and you are good to go.

For now, rasa is compatible just with TensorFlow version 2.1.1 and python 3.6 or 3.7

Reference Link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63580331/12600579

Comment: Tks so much for your empathy. However I still came up against with another error.
To be detailed, when I run `pip3 install rasa`, the process stops when coming to ujson package, and "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required" as well.
I have tried many ways shown in StackOverFlow, Github or Rasa Community. I installed MS tools, VS Studio 2019, install ujson directly but the error still appears. 
Any idea about that? Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you please share the exact error - after installing ujson package and MV C++ 14.0 ?

Comment: I have solved it, tks for caring. The error is still the same. But, I just re-try to uninstall, install ujson package and ignore the error about MV C++ 14.0. And that's it, my chatbot works.